# NodeJs Says Document has been deleted but it is not deleting it

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using nodejs and mongoDB.

I am trying to delete a document from a collection by giving it the _id.

So I'm using this:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db("myDatabase");
    console.log(req.params.id);
    var myquery = { _id: "5c9e0e721b27d11d38dca8da" };
    dbo.collection("myCollection").deleteOne(myquery, function(err, obj) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document deleted");
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Console is showing 1 document deleted but it's not deleting anything and it's not throwing any errors either.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is in `obj` in callback?

Comment: Maybe you need to use ObjectId class for query http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/ObjectID.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obj will contain a `deletedCount` which probably says 0. Trying to delete a non-existent object is not a failure.

And as @iofjuupasli points out, you probably need to have _id in your filter to be an actual ObjectID, like:

`var myquery = { _id: ObjectId("5c9e0e721b27d11d38dca8da") };`

Comment: That's giving me and error:  ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined

Comment: You need to import it from the mongodb package.

`const { MongoClient, ObjectId } = require('mongodb');`

If you are using node 8+. Otherwise, import them individually.